# LaTeX: How to create left aligned paragraphs and right aligned authors of paragraphs

Tags: latex, page-break

Please help me in creating LaTeX document with the following structure

```
Text
Author

Text
Author
```

Where Text is a block of 2-10 lines left aligned and Author is one line aligned to the right, and I need these Text+Author blocks to always appear on the same page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use `\nobreak` to avoid page break.
- Use `\raggedright` for left alignment, `{` and `}` to restrict the effect of the macro `\raggedright` and empty line before `}`.
- Use `\hfill` to shift Author to the right.

---

```
{\raggedright
Please help me in creating LaTex document with the following structure
Where Text is a block of 2--10 lines left aligned and Author is one line aligned to the right, and I need these Text+Author blocks to always appear on the same page. 

}

\nobreak
\hfill se\_pavel

{\raggedright
Please help me in creating LaTex document with the following structure
Where Text is a block of 2--10 lines left aligned and Author is one line aligned to the right, and I need these Text+Author blocks to always appear on the same page. 

}

\nobreak
\hfill se\_pavel
```

Comment: That is where I was going too...and if you need to do this more than twice wrap it all up in a `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment` or equivalent.

Comment: `\raggedright`, `\nobreak`, `\hfill` have less letters than \begin{someenviroment}...\end{someenviroment}.